# What non-component materials are required for wizard spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard

I am currently playing a wizard, and trying to plan ahead. I am making the assumption that all published spells are common and known to him, so while he cannot cast them yet, he is aware of them all, and how they work.

As such he is planning ahead, trying to gather whatever he can to make those spells work when (if) he ever learns to cast them.

Examples:

> **Scrying** (Divination, level 4)
>
> Items belonging to a potential target: likeness or picture; possession or garment; body part (lock of hair, nail etc)

> **Teleport** (Conjuration, level 7)
>
> Items from a location: associated object taken within the last 6 months

> **Dream** (Illusion, level 5)
>
> Items belonging to a potential target: body part (lock of hair, nail etc)

> **Infernal calling** (Conjuration, level 5)
>
> Items belonging to a devil: talisman

> **Animate dead** (Necromancy, level 3)
>
> Something to animate: pile of bones; corpse of a medium or small humanoid

I have been through all the spells that I can find, but my question is: **are there any items I have missed that are not material components, but have a specified positive effect on the spell in the same way as the above items.**

I only care about the wizard spell list using all official sources (including optional spells such as from TGtE and dunamancy from EGtW).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123636/discussion-on-question-by-seriousbri-what-non-component-materials-are-required-f).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a list of all known wizard spells with non-component materials:

- [*Scrying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying) (Divination, level 4):

  > Items belonging to a potential target: likeness or picture;
  > possession or garment; body part (lock of hair, nail etc)
- [*Teleport*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/teleport) (Conjuration, level 7):

  > Items from a location: associated object taken within the last 6 months
- [*Dream*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dream) (Illusion, level 5):

  > Items belonging to a potential target: body part (lock of hair, nail etc)
- [*Infernal calling*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/infernal-calling) (Conjuration, level 5):

  > Items belonging to a devil: talisman
- [*Animate dead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-dead) (Necromancy, level 3):

  > Something to animate: a pile of bones, or a corpse of a Medium or
  > Small humanoid
- [*Find the path*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-the-path) (Divination, level 6):

  > An object from the location you wish to find

Comment: For "Find the path" the object from the location you wish to find IS a component.